# show domain user name in google sites

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

This is probably very basic but I want to create a web app script that will display a `welcome to ...google domain username` in a google site.

Attempts such as this so far have failed..

```
// The code below will display the email address of the person running the script
Browser.msgBox(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find this in the documentation in the [base class description](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_base)

you can try the following

```
app.add(app.createLabel('Active user login id:' +  Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()));
app.add(app.createLabel('Efective user login id:' +  Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()));
```

Maybe an idea to put those functions within the [html service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/html_service).

[Working doGet() example](https://sites.google.com/a/lagaroo.com.br/dev-test/home/dev-test-user-info)